# Android: Offset ImageView in Center slightly

Tags: android-xml

[image]

We say that the following image is in the center. To do this I use the following code.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It has been working for a deadcenter positioning. I would like to do the following, and just offset it slightly upwards. As you see I do not want the image to cross the center line (I know how to fix that by adding an invisible view).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found a post giving me another hint at the fake view idea, making the fake view 100dp long, the bottom padding of the fake view 100dp long (so it would be pushed down) then aligning my views bottom with the bottom of the fake view, perfect.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. I even did not need the `paddingBottom` in the anchor view.